Are ants okay on my raspberry bush?
This is my second year with this bush, and it’s really taking off. I’ve noticed ants in the large planner running all through the dirt, but no issues at all. The past couple days I’ve noticed them climbing the stocks, and today when the first flower bloomed it was filled with 5 ants and they are gathering on various parts of the plant. Are they beneficial or should I be concerned?

Look closer and see if they are farming aphids, or otherwise doing actual damage. gathering nectar from the flowers might be innocuous. having aphids suck on the leaves to make food for ants - not innocuous.

Basically, if you don't find aphids or any pests on the plant that means ants are not causing any visible harm to the plant.
But if there is the presence of any aphids or signs of plant stress you need to address the issue.
